# Function Input is False

Tags: excel, vba

So here is how I call the function:

```
FilePathLoD(FirewallAssy)
```

And the function is:

```
Function FilePathLoD(FileName as String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
FilePathLoD = "E:\List of Drawings"
Workbooks.Open (FilePathLoD & "\" & FileName & "LoD.xlsm")
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

When I call the function the strings are parsed together as such.
E:\List of Drawings\FalseLoD.xlsm

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you are using an inputbox to collect a filename from the user and you want to stop execution if the user presses Cancel instead of supplying a filename and clicking OK.

Comment: The FirewallAssy is the first instance of this string in the line of code. No input is required. I guess my question is why does FirewallAssy turn into False?

Comment: Place a `Debug.Print FirewallAssy` immediately before the call and see what it says the value is which is being passed.  And put a `Debug.Print FileName` as the first statement inside the function so we can see what is being received.

Answer (score 0):

**FileName** is the first parameter of the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811.aspx). Change it to **fname** to avoid confusion.

Change this to a **Sub** procedure. You are not returning a value; simply implementing a method. A Sub is more appropriate than a Function for this operation.

```
Sub FilePathLoD(fName as String)
    Dim fPath as String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Activewindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    fPath = "E:\List of Drawings"
    Workbooks.Open (fPath & "\" & fName & "LoD.xlsm")
    Activewindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Call it as a procedure.

```
FilePathLoD FirewallAssy 
'... or,
Call FilePathLoD(FirewallAssy)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm confused (as usual).  I successfully ran the original code (after changing the return value the OP was setting so that it referred to a directory I had on my computer) - i.e. it opened the file and returned the path.  While I agree 100% (maybe even 110%!) with your suggestions, I don't see how they explain why the original code is setting the value of FileName to False when the OP runs the code.